# Can't log in with OpenID using Google Chrome

Tags: support, openid, google-chrome

I made the mistake of registering on Stack Overflow a while back with an Appspot OpenID, and not the real Google one. I have got some good rep, and don't want to start again or lose answers to my questions.

When I try to log into SO using Chrome I get this error:

> Positive assertion sent with OpenID version 1.1 but Identifier discovery suggested it would be 2.0.

for my OpenID.

And weirdly when I click the Google icon on the login page, I get logged in with an `unknown(google)` account automatically.

How do I go about creating a valid Google OpenID and then adding it to my SO account? I seem to be able to log in OK with Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a new account
2. note the numeric user IDs or user page URLs of both the "new" and "old" accounts
3. email us, at the address provided at the bottom of every web page, both account user IDs

We can merge them for you no problem.

Answer (score 1):

What is the url to your `unknown(google)` account on Stack Overflow?

We can move your Google OpenID from it to your [main Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222217/joec).

Also, do you have an `unknown(google)` account here on Meta?  We can fix that, as well, given its url.  If not, you can [add your Google OpenID to it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/).